# Disable auto create folder and file ckfinder

Tags: ckfinder

i have folder images and ckeditor, ckfinder

- myproject/images
- myproject/ck/ckeditor
- myproject/ck/ckfinder

When i click browser button in editor, ckfinder will auto copy folder and file from myproject/images to myproject/ck/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/Images

I want to disable this

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Posting your configuration file would definitely help, but be careful as it may have some sensitive data (like the license key).

My guess would be that in your configuration file `Thumbnails.Dir` points to the wrong path. Adjust it to point e.g. to `myproject/_thumbs` (but not to `myproject/images/_thumbs`, otherwise the `_thumbs` folder will be created infinitely).

CKFinder  needs some place where it can store thumbnails of your real images. I assume that `myproject/ck/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/Images` was exaclt that - thumbnails that landed in a weird location for some reason.